About NIZK with Preprocessing
This is the first time I ask a question on StackExchange, so please forgive me for any mistake. I am trying to understand the paper "Threshold Cryptosystems from Threshold Fully Homomorphic Encryption" of Boneh et al. [BGG+17] and have some questions about the NIZK with preprocessing (a.k.a PZK in Section 3.3.1, see picture below).

I will use the same notation as the author, namely $\sigma_P$ and $\sigma_V$ are generated by $\mathsf{PZK}.\mathsf{Setup}$.
First Question.
For the first question, the authors mentioned two constructions of the PZK, namely [DMP88] and [LS90]. However, I tried to check both constructions and noticed the following:

In the first paper [DMP88], the author stated that using $(\sigma_P,\sigma_V)$ multiple times might leak information about $\sigma_P$, this means that we must use $\sigma_P$ very few times, or even have to generate new $(\sigma_P,\sigma_V)$ every time we prove a new statement, am I correct?



In the second paper [LS90], Section 2, the authors need a preprocessing state where the length of  $\sigma_P$ and $\sigma_V$ must depend on the length of $x \in L$. (The prover chooses matrices $S_1,S_2,\dots,S_k$ of size $n$, which is the size of the statement graph $G_x$. The protocol is as below picture.) Therefore, for each new statement in $L$ say, $x' \in L$ it might holds that the size of $G_{x'}$ will be different from $G_x$ (unless the Karp reduction algorithm $f$ from $L$ to Hamiltionian graphs has the property that if $|x|=|x'|$ then $|G_x|=|f(x)|=|f(x')|=|G_{x'}|$) and thus in this case, we have to restart the preprocessing state with $x'$, am I correct? If this is the case, then I am confused that the syntax of [BGG+17] for letting the setup algorithm to be independent of $x$. I have not checked the construction from Section 3 forward in [LS90], but the construction requires one-way permutation and trapdoor permutation, which are not known to have instantiation from lattice.


So in both cases, we might have to generate a new string $(\sigma_P,\sigma_V)$ every time we prove a new statement. Is it correct? If yes, then we might not be able to apply the PZK to construct the universal thresholdizer since we will have to use the strings  $(\sigma_P,\sigma_V)$ to prove multiple statements (say, the message signing queries in Section 8.2 of [BGG+17].
Second Question.
My second question is that in the definition of zero-knowledge of PZK in Definition 3.4 above, is it "adaptive zero-knowledge"? Because if we want to use ZKP to construct signatures with adaptive chosen attack, then adaptive zero-knowledge will be required to simulate the proofs where the messages will be chosen after publishing the parameters. However, according to the definition, the simulator must simulate the string $\sigma_V$ based on $X$, which is non-adaptive zero knowledge to me.
Reference.
[BGG+17] Threshold Cryptosystems from Threshold Fully Homomorphic Encryption (https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/956.pdf).
[DMP88] Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge with Preprocessing (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/0-387-34799-2_21.pdf).
[LS90] Public Verifiable Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge Proofs (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-38424-3_26.pdf).

Hi Minh Pham and welcome. Although related questions are generally allowed, it is often better to split them apart, asking / handling them one by one. That makes it easier for us to take in all the information, and some people may be better at answering one of the three related questions. It also makes it easier for future readers to find their exact question without having to deal with all that complexity.

Hi Maarten Bodewes.  Does this mean that I need to split this one into several post? Since I am actually asking questions about the same paper that I do not understand. Maybe I can try to enumerate them in an easier way to understand, or just ask the most necessary question to me. Thank you for replying me.

Yes, that's what he is saying! The idea is that stackexchange should serve as a ressource useful for others with similar questions, so we usually prefer to have single question - single answer formats. It's perfectly fine to ask multiple questions about the same paper. If it helps, you can add pointers to your other questions in each of those, to clarify that they are parts of the same broader goal

Hi, does anyone know whether for a language $L$ and the set HAMILTONIAN-GRAPHS of graphs having hamiltonian cycle, the map $f$ that maps $x \in L$ to $f(x)$ in HAMILTONIAN-GRAPHS has the property that: If $|x_1|=|x_2|$ then the number of vertices of $f(x_1)$ is equal to the number of in $f(x_2)$? This is because in the question above, we need the PZK to prove multiple statements $x \in L$, but the preprocessing string depends on the number of vertices in $G$, thus this is only possible if the number of vertices are the same for all $x \in L$.
